# Application crash on accessing the TableViewCell in heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Application crashes on trying to access [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] in the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] someBOOLProperty]) {
        return kSomeHeight;
    } 

    return kDefaultHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

We do not have `tableViewCell` object at the time above method is called.

I think using [`tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`] inside the above delegate is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

`-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will call the delegate's `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, so you've got a loop which will crash your app.  You need to find a way to map indexPaths to `someBOOLProperty` values in a way that doesn't rely on fetching the cell with `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of what Ali3n said, I think you would need to use the data set your table is based off of to determine cell height, rather than using the table contents (which may not exist yet).